# pandas `rolling` does not know its own functions

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a `pandas` series `foo`, [`foo.mad()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mad.html) computes the mean absolute deviation of `foo`. So, one might think that `foo.rolling(10).mad()` would compute the rolling mean absolution deviation, by analogy with, say [`foo.rolling(10).std()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.std.html). But when I do that, I get an attribute error: `'Rolling' has no attribute 'mad'`. Is there a canonical way to deal with it (for the particular function `mad` it is not too difficult to roll one's own, since it does something quite simple, but it seems morally wrong)

Comment: if they haven't implemented a `rolling` helper method, you can just `apply` it, e.g.: `foo.rolling(10).apply(pd.Series.mad)`

Comment: @tdy 's answer works or you can cast the `Rolling` object to a series, then use its `mad` function

Comment: morally wrong?  it wont be a bad idea as well if you contributed the function to the library; we'd all be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Series methods that don't yet have a corresponding `rolling` implementation, use [`rolling.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html), e.g.:

```
foo.rolling(10).apply(pd.Series.mad)
```